# Unable to access react app running in docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have seen this question asked different ways on SO.  However, I have not been able to find an answer that works for me.  Perhaps I haven't done the right search.  So here I go.  I'm brand new to docker and have deployed a simple react app using docker.  I am able to hit the react app when I run it locally on my host, but when I try to access it from the host while running in the container, my luck runs out.
I understand that the issue is that the container is listening on its loopback interface, but it should listen on all intefaces (0.0.0.0).  My issue is that I am not sure how to do that.  I've seen instructions on how to do it for a node js app, for python http.server, etc.  But not for a react app.

My app is super straightforward.  I've created an app using create-react-app.  I am able to run it locally and see the react page (http://localhost:3000).  I've create a standard Dockerfile for a react app:

```
FROM node:12.15.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I then built and ran it using the following commands:

```
docker build -t sampleapp .
docker run -p 3000:3000 -d sampleapp
```

And as mentioned am not able to see the app on http://localhost:3000 
Any help would be ver appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.env.development`

`PORT=3000`

If you don't have .env.development then make it and add this env var and see if it works.

Comment: thanks for the info.  i think there was an issue with the centos instance that i had inherited from the previous person.  i setup my own fresh vm, installed docker, et al, and was able to deploy without an issue.

Comment: @HandsomeWayfarer do you have any issue since so? I am still stuck on the same issue as your but I saw many post where people are using NGINX on top of it because of some refresh that are causing 404